# Что значит "m" в начале имени переменной?

Tags: java, android, code-style

Часто встречаю в коде переменные, название которых начинается с одной буквы, которую я не всегда могу связать с контекстом. Например:

```
mCtx
mDBHelper
mDB
mTabHost
```

Прочитав [соглашение](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) информации что значит буква m в этих переменных не нашел.

Comment: это что-то из родственников венгерской нотации, скорее всего, это абсолютно бесполезный префикс, на тему которого не стоит заморачиваться.

Comment: В венгерской нотации используется префикс [`m_`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Examples). Такие префиксы контекстно-зависимые, нужно больше информации. Может это привязка к какой-то реализации базы, или автору, или месту ее применения/расположения - все что угодно, чтобы правильно сгруппировать инструменты. Вариант @Etki тоже не лишен смысла, смотря какие Вы преследуете цели.

Comment: для [примера](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Request.java#L65)

Comment: в примере `m` - однозначно `member`

Comment: Это устаревшее. Пишите, как в Java, без всяких m. IDE всё равно подстветит поля иначе, чем локальные переменные.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

В Java-based разработке использование префиксов *m* и *s* при именовании переменных [рекомендовано *Google*](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions) для андроид-разработчиков:

- Префикс *m* (member) используется для именований непубличных нестатических полей классов (напр. mField).
- Префикс *s* (static) используется для именований статических полей классов (напр. sField).
- Константы именуются полностью прописными буквами с разделением нижней чертой (напр. FIELD_CONST).
- Прочие поля классов и локальные переменные именуются без префиксов с маленькой буквы.

Сделано это для того, чтобы визуально отделять поля класса от локальных переменных, что в свою очередь идет от того, что именование переменных одного значения в андроид-разработке принято писать одинаково. То есть:

```
public class SomeClass {
Field mField;

  public SomeClass (Field field) {
      mField = field;
  }
}
```

Правильно это, удобно ли и прочие отвлеченные одобрения либо осуждения оставим в стороне - таковы рекомендации разработчикам под платформу *Android*.
Кроме того, весь фреймворк *Android* написан по этим соглашениям и часто заглядывая в исходники как то привыкаешь к такому стилю, иной кажется уже ошибочным, а читать код не придерживающийся такого стиля становится некомфортно (все это применительно исключительно к коду андроид-приложения).
Лично у меня в IDE настроено автоматическиое выставление нужных префиксов где это требуется.

Ну и конвенция *Java* не дает подобных рекомендаций - предлагается именовать все переменные и поля классов с маленькой буквы и без каких-либо префиксов, поэтому если вы не андроид-разработчик вы не должны именовать поля префиксами.

**UPDATE**

И вот [опубликована](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) конвенция *Google Java Style*, где [внезапно сказано](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names) буквально следующее:

> В стиле Google особые префиксы и суффиксы, как например name_, mName, s_name и kName **не** используются.

Так же [сказано](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.5-non-constant-field-names):

> Не константные поля класса (статические и другие) пишутся в lowCamelCase-стиле.

PS: какая-то засада. Столько привыкал к этим "m" теперь отвыкать опять что-ли ..

**UPDATE2**

Перевод [статьи  Cédric Beust](https://habrahabr.ru/post/333596/), человека, ответственного за появление префиксов для полей класса в рекомендациях по оформлению  кода Android приложения, где он объясняет, как такое произошло.

Comment: А как называть тогда геттеры и сеттеры: getmField, getMField, getMfield или getField?

Comment: @kostya Нет, геттеры/сеттеры называются, как обычно - getField, setField - в IDE [есть настройка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/479646/177345) для при автогенерации таких геттеров/сеттеров.

Answer (score 3):

Я могу предполагать, что этот префикс `m` соответствует слову `member` и используется для обозначения членов класса, чтобы отличать их от локальных переменных.

Эта традиция идет от Microsoft MFC.