# Настройка автозасоздания setter'ов и getter'ов в Inteliji IDEA и Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Как настроить автоматическое создание `getter'ов` и `setter'ов` в Inteliji IDEA (и AS), чтобы, при создании методов, пропускалась буква `m`, если она стоит первой?

---

Например, если у меня есть переменная `mWord`, IDEA создает метод `getmWord`, а нужно `getWord`.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30070317/3212712) и [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22977787/3212712)

Comment: не проще ли следовать общепринятой конвенции и не использовать ненужный префикс?

Comment: @Etki [конвенция для андроид-разработчиков](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) обязывает использовать префиксы m и s для непубличных полей класса и статических полей класса соответственно.

Comment: @pavlofff не знал, что для андроида есть своя конвенция, отличная от обычной java (и это отвратительно, если честно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В  настройках - *Editor->Code Style->Java*, вкладка *Code Generation*

В строку *Field:* в колонке *Name Prefix* пишите `m`, в строку *Static field:* в колонку *Name Prefix*  пишите `s`.

Теперь при автогенерации геттеров и сеттеров буквы `m` и `s` из имен методов будут опускаться, а при именовании полей классов предлагаться имена с `m` и `s` в начале, для простых и статических полей класса соответственно.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Code</kbd> → <kbd>Generate</kbd> → <kbd>Getter and Setter</kbd>

Жмём кнопку <kbd>...</kbd> после комбо-бокса *Getter Template*. Копируем шаблон *IntelliJ Default* и слегка его модифицируем:

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))

#if ($StringUtil.length($name) > 1 && $StringUtil.startsWith($name, 'm'))
    #set($name = $name.substring(1))
#end

#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  get##
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

Теперь жмём кнопку <kbd>...</kbd> после комбо-бокса *Setter Template*. Копируем шаблон *IntelliJ Default* и модифицируем:

```
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end

#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($StringUtil.length($name) > 1 && $StringUtil.startsWith($name, 'm'))
    #set($name = $name.substring(1))
#end

void set${name}($field.type $paramName) {
  #if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
      this.##
    #else
      $classname.##
    #end
  #end
  $field.name = $paramName;
}
```